# django printing tuple-keyed dictionary

Tags: python, django

I have a dictionary with tuples as keys. e.g.: {('tags','1'): 'name', ('name','first'):'rik', ('name','last'):'atee'}

In django, how do I print the value at ('name','first'), for example? I can do it with dict.items.1, or dict.items.2 - but ordering becomes an issue then.

Comment: Serious question. Why are you using tupels as keys?

Comment: Serious answer: don't do this. Have your view function munge the data into a form the template can access easily – that's what it's supposed to do in the first place.

Comment: as for why: http://pycassa.github.com/pycassa/assorted/composite_types.html

Comment: I understand why you'd end up with data like it at some point. My point is that templates never *need* to access data by arbitrary keys. If you only need to print the value at `('name', 'first')`, your view can pass that value to the template directly. If you need to print all the values of the dictionary in a specific order, have your view create a list of the values in the given order. While it's often convenient to just hand what you get from the database directly to the template, there's no reason to expect that this will always be the right thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Django templating language is intentionally restrictive in what it allows you to reference.

For instance you must use the dot operator to access attributes AND dictionary elements which means the keys you reference *must* be strings.

From docs:

> Variable names must consist of any letter (A-Z), any digit (0-9), an underscore (but they must not start with an underscore) or a dot.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups

Your options are to either (a) use your view to munge the tuple-keys into a string-format or (b) you can use a different templating engine which allows you to reference with arbitrary keys.

Option (b) isn't actually as bad as it sounds as their are templating languages for Django which are designed as a superset to Django's templating language so (theoretically) all your old templates work and you just get more functionality. I advise you checkout the [Jinja templating language](https://www.google.com/search?q=jinja+django), it has the functionality you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Any values in the dictionary can be accessed by their corresponding keys

So...

```
>>> foo = {('tags','1'): 'name', ('name','first'):'rik', ('name','last'):'atee'}
>>> foo[('name','first')]
'rik'
```

However tuples-as-keys will probably just end up being confusing and error-prone, why not use something like `{"tags": ['name'], "first":'rik', "last":'atee'}`?

Comment: Since this is a Django question, I'm guessing he's looking for the Django template variable syntax to do this, not pure Python.

Comment: @millimoose - correct. FWIW I am using tuples as keys as this is the output of pycassa database query. It looks odd but there are many advantages to it.